# Deploy failed on Netlify for my Gatsby app based on gatsby starter blog

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I used Gatsby starter blog for my website. The last time I tried to deploy I got the following error.

```
1:54:59 PM: error
1:54:59 PM: Your plugins must export known APIs from their gatsby-node.js.
1:54:59 PM: The following exports aren't APIs. Perhaps you made a typo or your plugin is outdated?
1:54:59 PM: See https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/ for the list of Gatsby Node APIs
1:54:59 PM: - The plugin "gatsby-source-filesystem@2.1.4" is exporting a variable named "createSchemaCustomization" which isn't an API.
1:54:59 PM: - The plugin "gatsby-source-filesystem@2.1.4" is exporting a variable named "createSchemaCustomization" which isn't an API.
```

I cleared the cache and tried to deploy again, but the problem is not solved.

When I try to build the project on my laptop every thing is fine. How can I fix the problem?

My [project files are on github](https://github.com/ahb360/amirbasiri.com) so you can check them.

Answer (score 1):

The version of `gatsby-source-filesystem` is using the API version of Gatsby that requires a version higher than you have in your dependencies. `createSchemaCustomization` was not introduced until Gatsby@^2.12.0 and above. The peer dependency for `gatsby-source-filesystem` should be updated to reflect this, but at this time it is only set to `^2.0.0`, so it did not give you a warning.

Update the Gatsby version to the latest or a compatible version (above 2.12) using:

```sh
yarn add gatsby@latest
```

Then make sure to push the `yarn.lock` and `package.json` to your repository, so Netlify will use the correct version during the build.